# Regular expression to keep indentation (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this string

```
'  select t1.*, t2.*
   from table1 t1
     join table t2
       on t1.id=t2.id_fk
'
```

I want to print it without the first spaces but keeping the indentation.

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
  join table t2
    on t1.id=t2.id_fk
```

Do you know guys how can I do it? I am using Oracle database with dbms_output.put_line method.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the first line has the minimum indentation, this is reasonably straight-forward. Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to extract the string of spaces at the beginning of the first line, and then `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace that string of spaces at the beginning of *every* line with a blank string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(s, '^' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, '^\s+'), '', 1, 0, 'm')
FROM data
```

Output:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
  join table t2
    on t1.id=t2.id_fk
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c13cf663f1504f6d9e8e81d190258fa2)

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick, nice explanation